# Grouped exposed filter is not available

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a filter within a view, which has multiple ranges;

i.e.

- 0-99
- 100-399
- 400-699
- 700-1000

I have seen this before when you *Add filter criteria*, you can select *grouped exposed filter* and I can set up the ranges in there. But in this instance, this option is not there and I'm not sure why not.

In the drupal code I found [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_filter.inc/function/views_handler_filter::can_build_group/7) which counts the options in `$this->operator_options()` - But I don't know what `$this->operator_options()` is meant to contain, or how you go about adding items to it through the back-end.

Comment: what is the type of data you are using?

Comment: They are floating point numbers 399.99, 500.00 etc

Comment: Have you tried using Better Exposed Filters? https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Facet API filters? check the [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) module

> The Facet API module allows site builders to easily create and manage faceted search interfaces. In addition to the UI components that come out of the box, themers and module developers can build their own widgets that can optionally be contributed back to Drupal.org. Facet API works with the core Search, Search API, and Apache Solr Search Integration modules (including Acquia Search) meaning that code and configuration can be reused as-is with the most popular search solutions available to Drupal. Refer to the documentation for more details.